# How to save a rendered component to memory?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, react-native, rendering

I'm developing a React Native application (although I think my issue applies to React in general) made of multiple screens.

So I've created a simple component to switch the screens:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { View } from 'react-native';

class AppNavComponent extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.screenCache_ = {};
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.props.route) throw new Error('Route must not be null');
        let route = this.props.route;
        if (this.screenCache_[route.routeName]) return this.screenCache_[route.routeName];
        let Screen = this.props.screens[route.routeName].screen;

        this.screenCache_[route.routeName] = (
            <View>
                <Screen/>
            </View>
        );

        return this.screenCache_[route.routeName];
    }

}

const AppNav = connect(
    (state) => {
        return {
            route: state.route,
        };
    }
)(AppNavComponent)

export { AppNav };
```

`this.props.screens` contains the list of screens, and `this.props.route` the route that needs to be displayed. The component works fine, but my problem is that I'd like to cache to memory certain screens because they are slow to render (a large list) and they lose the scrolling position whenever React re-render them.

In the example above, I've tried to save the rendering to `this.screenCache_` but that's probably not the right approach as the screens are still re-rendering when I load them, go to another page, and go back to them.

I guess that's a common problem but I can't find any information on Google. Any suggestion on how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to efficiently cache the component in the way you go about it, because the DOM still would need to repaint it later, which is the heavy part.

A simpler solution, and I think slack does that under the hood, is to use `display: none` instead.

`<View style={shouldDisplayScreen ? {} : { display: none }} />`

---

PS. You might want to set `shouldComponentUpdate` to `false`, if the component is currently not being displayed to avoid performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

Your first answer shouldn't be to cache things in React. There are a lot of other ways to increase performance. Start by reading the performance section of their documentation. There are some very simple solutions to increase performance right off the bat.

[React Native Documentation: Performance](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html)

Some other things you can do to increase performance:

1. Remove the console.logs and other loggers.
2. Use componentShouldUpdate to ensure that you only re-render when you need to.
3. If you are using redux take a look at Selectors. If you have data that needs to be calculated and you are doing needless repetitive calculations, you can memoize that data.

I think that your problem comes from something from the React Native docs so run through those things first before trying to do things overly complicated.

For a point of reference, one of my buddies recently made a VR application doing multiple calculations that updated redux state every time the gyroscope moved and rerendered objects on the DOM hundreds of times per second. React Native can take a lot so don't worry about caching yet.

Comment: What bothers me more than the slow performance is the fact that the scroll position is lost. The list components of React Native are currently buggy and this kind of thing cannot be worked around, so an acceptable solution in the meantime would be to cache that list to memory.

Comment: There should be a navigation library that can save your scrolling position efficiently. Check out the [awesome-react-native](https://github.com/jondot/awesome-react-native) repo to see if there is anything there

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a navigation library to handle screens. Check https://reactnavigation.org

For example, use a StackNavigator with two routes, i.e. list and detail.

```
const app = StackNavigator({
  Index: { screen: Some list view },
  Detail: { screen: some detail page },
});
```

Also if the ListView is slow for you, try the new FlatList or SectionList component that’s available since 0.43. They are more performant.